# PowerShell: How can this be? Debugging gets a different result than running

Tags: powershell-3.0

```
$array=@("g")
function foo()
{
    $array += "h"
    Write-Host $array
}

& {
    $array +="s"
    Write-Host $array
}
foo

Write-Host $array
```

When I set a break point and single step this script, I get the above output.  But when I run it with PowerShell ISE, I get a different output:

```
PS C:\power-scripts> C:\power-scripts\ScopeExample.ps1
Hit Line breakpoint on 'C:\power-scripts\ScopeExample.ps1:8'
[DBG]: PS C:\power-scripts>> 
g s
[DBG]: PS C:\power-scripts>> 
g h
[DBG]: PS C:\power-scripts>> 
g

PS C:\power-scripts> C:\power-scripts\ScopeExample.ps1
s
h
g
```

Does anyone know why this is? Debugging should act the same as running a script without debugging.

Comment: Or simpler compare pasting your code directly into the console versus running it as a script. With the breakpoint or in the console the `+=` starts with the value from the outer scope, without it doesn't. Looks like a bug to me but I can't find it documented or discussed.

Comment: When pasting the code into the console, the results are the same as when the code is run from a script file. It’s only when you single step through the code are the results different.